# Actionscript 3 Error 1009

Tags: error-handling, actionscript, helper

When I export my application to device central I get this error constantly popping up in the output window "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. atsquareslide_fla::MainTimeline/test()
This is the code that I have right now:

`   import flash.events.Event;

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent; 
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode; 
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
function loop(e:Event)
{  
rock1.rotation +=10;
rock2.rotation +=10;
rock3.rotation +=10;
rock4.rotation +=10;
rock5.rotation +=10; 
widerock.rotation +=10;
rock1.y +=10;
rock2.y +=10;
rock3.y +=10;
rock4.y +=10;
rock5.y +=10;  
widerock.y +=10;
if (rock1.y >= 872.9)
{
    rock1.y = -46.75;
} 
if (rock2.y >= 872.9)
{
    rock2.y = -84.75;
}
if (rock3.y >= 872.9)
{
    rock3.y = -69.75;
}
if (rock4.y >= 872.9)
{
    rock4.y = -230.9;
}
if (rock5.y >= 872.9)
{
    rock5.y = -230.9;
} 
if (widerock.y >= 872.9)
{
    widerock.y = -547.8;
} 
}`
```

Something is obviously wrong with rock one but I have no idea what it is or how to fix it. 
Please help!

Comment: please add new line signs into your code

Comment: that is better right?

Comment: [Read this and see if it helps](http://martywallace.com/post/as3-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-object-reference).

Comment: It didn't really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED_TO_STAGE)

It fires when everything is added to the stage.